# How can I pass $scope.gridOptions.data as parameter in function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

The method 1 works perfectly, when I try to write it as a function as in the second method 2, ui-grid Is not updated, 
what is the good way to do that?

**Method 1 :**

```
 $scope.grid_update= function () {

    $http.get('/get_data').success(function (data) {

        $scope.gridOptions.data = data;

    }).error(function () {alert("Error")});
};
```

**Method 2**

```
// Function declaration
update_from_MySQL = function (URL,control) {

    $http.get(URL).success(function (data) {
        control=data;

    }).error(function () {alert("Error");});
 };

 //Call function
 $scope.grid_update =function({
 update_from_MySQL('/get_data',$scope.gridOptions.data); 
 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to pass entire $scope.gridOptions.data and modify it inside the function by overwriting it. Better approach you can take is by returning promise object from update function and use this promise in grid_update:

```
function update_from_MySQL (URL) {
  return $http.get(URL)
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.data
    })
};

$scope.grid_update = function() {
  update_from_MySQL('/get_data')
    .then(function (data) {
      $scope.gridOptions.data = data
    })
}
```

Or, you could still make your original solution work if you were to pass `$scope.gridOptions` into grid_update:

```
$scope.grid_update = function() {
  update_from_MySQL('/get_data', $scope.gridOptions)
};
```

and mutate this object in `update_from_MySQL`:

```
$http.get(URL).success(function (data) {
  control.data = data
})
```

But this is not ideal workflow.